# automatically stop recording in AudioRecord class

Tags: android, audio

I found the code for storing audio in .wav format from this [link](https://github.com/roman10/roman10-android-tutorial/tree/master/AndroidWaveRecorder).The code has two buttons to start and stop the recording.I want to stop the audio recording after sometime.It uses the AudioRecord class of Android to store audio.Is it possible to do so?

```
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.androidwaverecorder/com.example.androidwaverecorder.MainActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at   com.example.androidwaverecorder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-19 08:20:00.688: E/AndroidRuntime(2405):     ... 11 more
04-19 08:31:55.766: E/Trace(2899): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-19 08:31:55.766: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-19 08:31:55.766: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-19 08:31:55.766: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-19 08:31:56.386: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-19 08:31:56.386: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-19 08:31:56.416: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
04-19 08:31:56.416: W/Trace(2899): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: Why don't you use a timer and call the logic of stop recording?

Comment: How to stop the timer thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution 
You can use AsyncTask to do this.

A brief explanation of how to do:
When you start your recording create a thread in another class which will be sleeping for required time period and then call your recorder stop function.

```
public class Auto_Stop_Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Integer> {
//int flag=0;
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        MainActivity.mRecorder.stop();
        MainActivity.mRecorder.reset();
        //flag=1;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

call this class after starting your recorder.

```
new Auto_Stop_Task().execute();
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in onCreate of MainActivity

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if (WavAudioRecorder.State.ERROR == mRecorder.getState()) {
                        mRecorder.release();
                        mRecorder = WavAudioRecorder.getInstanse();
                        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mRcordFilePath);
                        btnControl.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        mRecorder.stop();
                        mRecorder.reset();
                        btnControl.setText("Start");
                    }
                }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, YOUR TIME IN MILLISEC);
```

**Edit**

```
 private static final String mRcordFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testwave.wav";
```

TO

```
String mRcordFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testwave.wav";
```

Comment: its showing error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method postDelayed(Runnable, long) from the type 
  Handler"

Comment: Change private static final String mRcordFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testwave.wav";   TO   String mRcordFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testwave.wav";

Comment: now i am getting a NULL pointer exception and the app doesn't even start.Do I have to add any permission?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidwaverecorder/com.example.androidwaverecorder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException.This is the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28501/discussion-between-mani-bharataraju-and-arun-c-thomas)